# Why is the client connection keep reconnect it self in heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm currently using Heroku to host a simple chat program, and I tried to use heroku logs -t to check the problem. I found that my client side will keep on connect to the server and disconnect itself.

I tried to send a message from the client side, and the server side also didnt receive anything.

[heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upVAt.png)

Server.js

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {
    origins: ['example.com']//my own domain
  }
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Welcome</h1>');
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  socket.on('newActivity',(msg)=>{
    socket.broadcast.emit('activity',msg);
  })
  socket.on('message',(msg)=>{
    console.log(msg);
    socket.broadcast.emit('message-broadcast',msg);
  })
});

http.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that you need to enable [session affinity](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity) on your Heroku app. If you're using WebSockets on Heroku, this will ensure that your WebSocket clients continue to stay connected to the same backend dyno.

This is important because Heroku is an ephemeral architecture: requests are usually routed to a random dyno and dynos are designed to be moved around/stopped/started all the time.

If you want to learn a bit more, read the article I linked above as well as the [Heroku Node + WebSockets documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets) that covers best practices and other related information.